# PyYAML Error: TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects

Tags: python-3.x, pyyaml

I'm trying to dump what perhaps a somewhat complex Class with YAML and am seeing the following error.  I don't know what `pickle` does, but I'm not engaged in any multithread programming to my knowledge.  This happens while running a pyunit unit test:

Any idea how to find the offending attribute?

```
 ERROR: test_multi_level_needs (test_needs.needs_TestCase)
 -----------------------------------------------------------
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/rsalemi/.../test_needs.py", line 240, in test_multi_level_needs
     print(yaml.dump(test2_comp))
   File ".../.../yaml/__init__.py", line 200, in dump        

  <snipped lots of stack trace>


    File ".../.../yaml/representer.py", line 91, in represent_sequence
      node_item = self.represent_data(item)
    File ".../.../yaml/representer.py", line 51, in represent_data
      node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
    File ".../.../yaml/representer.py", line 341, in represent_object
      'tag:yaml.org,2002:python/object:'+function_name, state)
    File ".../.../yaml/representer.py", line 116, in represent_mapping
      node_value = self.represent_data(item_value)
    File ".../.../yaml/representer.py", line 51, in represent_data
      node = self.yaml_multi_representers[data_type](self, data)
    File ".../.../yaml/representer.py", line 315, in represent_object
      reduce = data.__reduce_ex__(2)
  TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects
```

Comment: You can search for signs of threading usage in your code as `test2_comp` appears to be using `_thread.RLock` somewhere.

Comment: Where is the code? You should at least show what is `test2_comp`. Using `dump()` instead of `safe_dump()` almost always indicates you are doing something wrong and/or dangerous.

Comment: I can't find any clear documentation on the advantage of safe_dump. Any suggestions? Thanks!  @anthon

Comment: When you use `safe_dump()` any special objects (roughly speaking anything that is **not** a Python `dict`, `list` or primitive type (string, int, float, boolean, None) needs a registered dumper. When you provide that dumper you know exactly what is written to the file and no unexpected representations show up.

Comment: @Anthon, a big advantage to this is that it gives a reasonable error message. The crashing object is a class I defined.